# How do you edit an embed when someone adds a reaction? DIscord.py

Tags: discord.py

I am new to discord.py and somewhat experienced with python.
I currently use the code below to edit an embed when I add a reaction.

```py
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    if payload.emoji == "✅":
        e = discord.Embed(
            title="Tic Tac Toe",
            description= "Play Tic Tac Toe",
            color=0xFF5733)
        e.add_field(name = "Choice", value = 'You have chosen Yes')
        
        await payload.reaction.remove(payload.user)
        await payload.message.edit(embed = e)
    elif payload.emoji == "":
        embed = ""
    
        await payload.reaction.remove(payload.user)
        await payload.message.edit(embed)
```

My end goal is to be able to play TicTacToe in Discord. I currently am trying to just test out reactions. I have absolutely no idea why it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [`on_raw_reaction_add()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_raw_reaction_add#discord.on_raw_reaction_add), you can't directly access to messages and reactions, you have to retrieve them:

```py
from discord.utils import get

@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    emoji = payload.emoji
    channel = client.get_channel(payload.channel_id)
    message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)
    reaction = get(message.reactions, emoji=emoji.name)

    if emoji.name == "✅":
        e = discord.Embed(
            title="Tic Tac Toe",
            description= "Play Tic Tac Toe",
            color=0xFF5733)
        e.add_field(name = "Choice", value = 'You have chosen Yes')

        await reaction.remove(payload.member)
        await message.edit(embed=e)
    elif emoji.name == "":
        await reaction.remove(payload.member)
        await message.edit(embed=None)
```

Comment: I replaced my code with your code, and it still did nothing. I did notice that the channel variable is not used.

Comment: I tested it again and it said that On_Raw_Reaction_Add has noo attribute payload.message

Comment: My bad, you have to use `payload.emoji.name` in the condition. I've also changed `message`

Comment: Whenever I use the revised code, it says that there is nothing called self.

Comment: Well, there's not `self` argument in your question or any cog so I can't help you

Comment: Okay, I will try to provide some of the code and the error message. @Mr_Spaar
Whenever I use the code: `channel = self.bot.get_channel(payload.channel_id)`, it shows an error message saying **[pyflakes] undefined name 'self'**.

Comment: Problem should be fixed now, I was pretty tired last night and didn't saw an error I made in the code I gave

Comment: I tried using the updated code and it did not work. I tried `channel = client.bot.get_channel(payload.channel_id)` and `channel = client.get_channel(payload.channel_id)` the first one gave me the error: **'Client' object has no attribute 'bot'.** The second gave no error, but it did not give any output.

Comment: If you have no output with `client.get_channel(...)`, you conditions aren't triggered. Have you changed `emoji` to `emoji.name` in your conditions (as in my answer) ?

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, could you validate it ?